# Neomutt goes to next message on page down, but not previous on page up

Tags: neomutt

Neomutt seems to have a strange feature: When I open a message with space, I can press `PageDown` to scroll down by a page. However, when this gets to the end of the message, it doesn't stop - it skips to the next message. But `PageUp` never goes to the previous message, and instead stops at the top.

Is there a way to make `PageDown` **not** go to the next message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the configuration option [pager_stop](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference#3-281-%C2%A0pager_stop).
Add `set pager_stop = yes` to your muttrc.